# Issue with UIImage on older iOS versions

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimage, ios11, distortion

I'm having a weird issue with UIImage. I assigned an image directly to a UIImageView on the storyboard and it works fine on iOS 11 but this app still needs support for iOS 8 and there the image looks all messed up.

What can I do?

Wrong image:

[image: Messed up image]

Correct image:

[image: Correct image]

Comment: What's the format of the image file?

Comment: It's a .png file